# NPM Pack / Nodejitsu ignores buried Node_modules folders

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, nodejitsu

It seems that NPM pack, and by extension, nodejitsu, do not like my node_modules folders. :*(

I currently am building a web app.

My web app's project folder structure is as follows:

Root

```
Engine(folder)                      Server(folder)    readme.md     package.json
```

(Multiple Folders)  (folder)(folder)   node_modules(folder)

```
                   easyimage,mongodb,mysql(folders)       socket.io (folder)

       node_modules(folder, NPM Pack ignores this)           node_modules(folder, NPM Pack ignores this)

                                                       Socket.io-client (folder, NPM Pack ignores this)
```

I hope everyone can see this structure alright!

The problem I am having is that when I run NPM Pack at the root directory, the entire directory structure is packed correctly, except for all of the node_modules folders below the first node_modules folder.

It is as if NPM pack completely ignores those node_modules folders. (The one below socket.io for instance).

Due to the fact NPM pack ignores these npm folders, jitsu is also ignoring them and I can't get my web app started.

How can I get NPM pack/nodejitsu to correctly package all of the node_modules folders correctly?

My current package.json file, at the root directory, looks like follows:
http://pastebin.com/SAU6rwb5

As you can see, I have attempted to use bundleDependencies to tell NPM Pack that I am trying to include some node_modules folders (modules?), but pack still ignores all of them... Also, if i include anything under "dependencies", NPM start creates a new (??) node_modules folder at the root directory... but at the root directory nothing needs node_modules... as you can see node_modules are used inside of the server folder.

How can I get NPM Pack to recognize the files and folders inside of all of the node_modules folders and pack them correctly?

Comment: node_modules isn't suppose to be included because it can be recreated with `npm install` if you have a package.json correctly set up, and in Nodejitsu this will happen automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*(jump to last paragraph if you want a really easy solution)*

I'm having a hard time understanding your app structure. I think I get what your trying to do though.
From https://npmjs.org/doc/folders.html , it actually goes into detail about when and why sub modules will or wont show up.

> When installing locally, npm first tries to find an appropriate prefix folder. This is so that npm install foo@1.2.3 will install to the sensible root of your package, even if you happen to have cded into some other folder.
>
> Starting at the $PWD, npm will walk up the folder tree **checking for a folder that contains either a package.json file, or a node_modules folder**. If such a thing is found, then that is treated as the **effective "current directory" *for the purpose of running npm commands***. (This behavior is inspired by and similar to git's .git-folder seeking logic when running git commands in a working dir.)
>
> **If no package root is found, then the current folder is used.**
>
> When you run npm install foo@1.2.3, then the package is loaded into the cache, and then unpacked into ./node_modules/foo. Then, any of foo's dependencies are similarly unpacked into ./node_modules/foo/node_modules/....

Bear With me for another quote...

> Cycles are handled using the property of node's module system that it walks up the directories looking for node_modules folders. **So, at every stage, if a package is already installed in an ancestor node_modules folder, then it is not installed at the current location.**
>
> Consider the case above, where `foo -> bar -> baz`. Imagine if, in addition to that, `baz` depended on `bar`, so you'd have: `foo -> bar -> baz -> bar -> baz ...`. However, since the folder structure is: foo/node_modules/bar/node_modules/baz, there's no need to put another copy of bar into `.../baz/node_modules`, since when it calls require("bar"), it will get the copy that is installed in `foo/node_modules/bar`.
>
> This shortcut is only used if the exact same version would be installed in multiple nested `node_modules` folders. It is still possible to have `a/node_modules/b/node_modules/a` if the two "a" packages are different versions. **However, without repeating the exact same package multiple times, an infinite regress will always be prevented.**

As far as the bundledDependencies:

> Upon publishing [this also applies to packing], npm will look in the node_modules folder. If any of the items there are not in the bundledDependencies array, then they will not be included in the package tarball.

I take this to mean that it will *only bundle the listed modules* in `./node_modules/` and specific sub-modules for a `./package.json` . Then of course as written above, it recursively walks down the directory tree again... so if it sees another `package.json` file in this directory npm will look and see if that has any bundled deps to include in the pack.

So as I understand it right now, since you have no packages in your base directory, your bundled dependencies in package.json doesn't *do anything*, and actually having items in your bundledDependencies field does more harm than good.

To fix you need to edit the `package.json` files to include these bundles at each level.

I have had this issue before when trying to get a packed then unpacked meteor app working on nodejitsu. I solved it in a different way. In the root folder of my app I included all of the top level node modules and explicitly set their version in my `package.json` file.

From what I understand your file structure is such:

```
    app
    +-- Engine
    +-- Server
    |   +-- socket.io
    |   |   `-- package.json
    |   |   +-- node_modules
    `-- readme.md
    `-- package.json
```

If this is so then you need to be editing the `package.json` under socket.io to include the bundled deps you want. Generally though you can trust the package maintainers to keep valid versions.(but in this case you can't?)

As for `Socket.io-client` not being packed that's a result of it being a dependency of socket.io.

If I was to suggest a way for you to make this easier for yourself, i'd suggest you to, in your **MAIN** top level `package.json` file, to include the dependencies you need for your app @ the specific version you need. If you need them bundled for some reason, add them into the bundled section, if you need sub modules at a different version than what the author intended. Consider making a folder called `package` or `vendor` and then placing the modules in there, in those you can edit the `package.json` and bundles their dependencies to your hearts content. Be sure though that you do not ignore any files or folders under you `vendor` or `packages` directory with `.npmignore` or `.gitignore` files.

**Alternatively, if this is too difficult (editing all theses files and specifying certain versions can be a pain) I'd suggest hosting your vendor packages some where where you could download them with a script, and then execute this script in the `postinstall` part of your package.json (take a read at https://npmjs.org/doc/scripts.html ... you would add this in the same section you have your "start" script.**

I hope that clarifies things.

Comment: This is exactly correct. Thanks blakmatrix. I'm not sure why the mongodb/socket.io guys didn't include any bundled dependencies in their package.json file, even though their modules clearly come with some dependencies packaged.. Or it could have been prepackaged by the engine I am using for my game.

Comment: Going to try putting my dependencies on the root directory and bundling them there... require should grab them right?